# SQL Server 2016 - SSRS Unable to Upload Report Models - smdl Files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, reporting, ssrs-2016

SSRS 2016 has major improvements and we've decided to migrate our 2008 servers. However, we and ran into a issue where we can't upload our old Report Models (.smdl files) via the web interface. All of the documentation states that these old models are deprecated, but will continue to work in SQL 2016.

Has anyone been able to figure this out? Can we use the SOAP web service to upload them? If so, do you have an example script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me --> creating an SSRS 2008 project and add the Report Models in there. Then deploy the report models to the SSRS 2016 server.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a bit old but hopefully it helps someone else. SMDL models are copied/migrated over if you use the RS.EXE utility to copy over data.